# How to extract data from a website to Excel?

Tags: excel, web

From [this](http://saudi.souq.com/sa-en/%D8%B9%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AC-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%B1-%D9%85%D9%86-anurex-2744400080/u/) site, there are the following values (located in the middle) :

```
Item EAN:   2724283785925
Sold by: GreenDiamond
```

What I want is to know how to extract values to Excel "or any program" so Column "A" is list of "Item EAN" (which is Not Variable and I enter it manually) and Column "B" is Extracted data for Value of "Sold by:" (which is Variable)

Can you help me please ?

I think we can use MACRO for this 
Something like this

```
Sub queryURL()

myURL = "URL;http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/PropertyProfileOverviewServlet?boro=" & Range("A1") & "&houseno=" & Range("A2") & "street=" & Range("A3") & "&go2=+GO+&requestid=0&t10=y"

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=myURL, Destination:=Range("A9"))
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

here is the sample code:

```
import java.io.File;
import jxl.*;
import jxl.write.*;
 /**
 *
 * @author Guokai.Wang
 */
 public class ExcelCreator 
 {
  /**
 * @param args the command line arguments
  */
  public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Cell cell;
    EN n1 = new EN(0, 3, 1.00);
    Label label = new Label(0, 2, "A label cell");
    // NumberFormat n_f = new NumberFormat(NumberFormat.CURRENCY_DOLLAR);
    // WritableCellFormat currencyFormat = new WritableCellFormat(n_f);
    WritableSheet sheet;
    WritableWorkbook book;

    try
    {
        book = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("test.xls"));
        sheet = book.createSheet("First", 0);

        // n2 = new EN(0, 4, f, currencyFormat);

        sheet.addCell(label);
        sheet.addCell(n1);
        // sheet.addCell(n2);

        cell = sheet.getCell(0, 2);
        System.out.println(cell.getContents());

        book.write();
        book.close();
    }
    catch(Exception exception) {exception.printStackTrace();}
    }
   }
```

you have to download jxl.jar

Comment: That's Java code. The question has nothing to do with Java.